# c - cpu cache associativity - theory and practice confusion

Tags: caching, cpu

### Context

Still reading a lot about cpu cache.
Debian 64 bit.
Intel core 2 duo, 4 way cache associativity.

What is expressed below is my current thinking. Please correct me if I am wrong, that is why I ask.

### Question

I often read on SO about loop performance and so on. But I feel a bit mistaken when I read that you have to access the next bytes because they are in the cache line. They often omit the fact that you can read multiple sections at a time with no risk.

I think most people don't insist enough on the cache associativity. I have a 4 way cache so I can have 4 cursors in my loop without it to boom my performances.

Why ? because 4 ways means that I have 4 lines in each set. it means as well that in case of a line collision, the memory controller is able to take another of the three other free for this address mapping.

That is why I tend to avoid buying direct mapped cache controlled cpu (don't find much of it anyway, in my world).

Better explained with a drawing of a fake situation (cache line 32 bytes, 8 bytes per integer, 4 way cache associativity) :

```
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
  ^       ^       ^
```

Read from left to right linearly.

Even if those three cursors are overlapping the region, they will not cause cache trashing.

So, the two only things to take care of are :

1) don't read more different sections in your loop than your cache associativity

2) be sure to access those in a linear fashion OR access already accessed regions by another cursor in that loop not long ago(diminish the risk of a trashing).

I just want to be sure that what I have just written is a correct assumption.
If I am not clear, please, tell me.

thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with C?

Comment: You and i know that c/c++ devs are much more up to answer than python devs or any higher language. And since C community is HUGE, that is the why.